# Override comment history order in backend

Tags: magento2, admin, template

I'm trying to override the template for the comment history of a order (the part next to the total of the order).

this is my path to layout .xml :

> app/code/Portail/Fournisseur/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_addcomment.xml

this is my path to my .tpl file

> app/code/Portail/Fournisseur/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/history.phtml

and this is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <referenceBlock name="order_history">
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Portail_Fournisseur::order/view/history.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </container>
</layout>
```

My module is enabled, i've done this :

1. setup:upgrade
2. setup:di:compile
3. setup:static-content:deploy
4. cache:clean
5. cache:flush

A similar issue added /Magento_Sales, but not working either. I'm on magento 2

> app/code/Portail/Fournisseur/view/adminhtml/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_order_addcomment.xml

EDIT : I've also updated my module version

Answer (score 1):

Solved :

Instead of override **sales_order_addcomment.xml**, I've override **sales_order_view.xml** and change to this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_history">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Codedecorator_Learn::order/view/history.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Also added this into my module :

```
<module name="Portail_Fournisseur" setup_version="1.0.0" active="true">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

Following blog post will help you about the same

https://www.codedecorator.com/blog/how-to-override-comment-history-order-in-backend/